# Need Regular Expression for Email Id with special characters .()<>\\" space ;

Tags: c#, jquery, regex, email

I need a Regular expression for Email Id that contains special characters like `.;<>[]\"` space and even @ sign.It should not allow any multiple spaces in between. The username can't start with a space but it may contain a space inbetween like

"John "Smith\@yahoo.com

The Email Id can be like below

```
very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com
```

The Regex should work with **C#** like this 
`[RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "E-mail is not valid")]` and with jQuery

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the input strings isolated, not inside a bigger text?

Comment: No they are not isolated

Comment: Then, you should provide the context. There is no regex that can match an email with spaces in the user name part without some specific boundary before it.

Comment: Yes the username can't start with space but single space is allowed in between like John Smith@yahoo.com

Comment: How can I know when the user name part of an email starts? Please provide example input where to search for matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```css
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" 
                runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Valid Email ID"
                    ValidationGroup="Submit" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" 
                    CssClass="requiredFieldValidateStyle"
                    ForeColor="Red" 
                    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">
                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will post this, but you should bear in mind that this might return unexpected results when used without boundaries/anchors:

```
([-a-zA-Z0-9_\\:;,(). @"[\]<>]+)@((?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6})
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yC9nG5/1).

This regex will work in both C# and JQuery since it does not use any named character classes, nor balancing groups, nor named capturing groups, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to validate mail:

```
^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

test regex: [see demo](http://www.systemtextregularexpressions.com/regex.match?p=XihbXHctXC5dKylAKChcW1swLTldezEsM31cLlswLTldezEsM31cLlswLTldezEsM31cLil8KChbXHctXStcLikrKSkoW2EtekEtWl17Miw0fXxbMC05XXsxLDN9KShcXT8pJA%3D%3D&t=dmFsaWRfdGVzdEBtYWlsLnJ1DQp0ZXN0ZWRAZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ0Kbm9Abm9ALmNvbQ0KZXJyb3JALnJ1DQp2YWxpZEBnbWFpbC5ydQ%3D%3D&op=2)